# MySQL Workbench : TroubleShooting Keys

Tags: mysql, key, mysql-workbench

I have a `php` script that creates a large temporary mysql table.

The creation of this table takes a ridiculous big time (more than 30 min !). So I decided to troubleshoot it. I'm sure that the problem is with the creation of the `Keys`.

I used `MySQL WorkBench` to do that, and now I'm facing a hard time understanding this statement :

```
/!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 /;
PRIMARY KEY (`CONC_ID`,`d_id_2`),
KEY `vo_marque_id` (`VM_id`),
KEY `CONC_ID` (`CONC_ID`,`d_id_2`)
/!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS /;
```

Does this mean that I have duplicate Keys for `CONC_ID`? or that I have a `Key` that points on it's self ?

Comment: how many rows  are involved ??

Comment: @scaisEdge The table contains ~50k rows

Comment: update your question and add  the sql code related  to your question  ..(not only a part of code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 /;
```

- `/!40014` means "execute this only when the MySQL server version is at least 4.0.14
- `SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS` stores the current value of `foreign_key_checks` in the variable `old_foreign_key_checks`
- then foreign key checks are disabled with `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0`

---

```
PRIMARY KEY (`CONC_ID`,`d_id_2`),
KEY `vo_marque_id` (`VM_id`),
KEY `CONC_ID` (`CONC_ID`,`d_id_2`)
```

- the index `conc_id` is superfluous, as it's the same as the primary key. You can safely delete it with `alter table <your_table> drop index conc_id;`

---

```
/!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS /;
```

- restores the value of `foreign_key_checks` with the variable used before. Again only if the version is greater than 4.0.14

Comment: Thank you for this answer :) Just a question, does a superfluous index (like `CONC_ID` in our example) can slow down the creation of the table ?

Comment: Depends on what you mean with "creation". Just creating the table, no, filling the table with data slows down, yes. But I would assume not that significantly.